# Finding the extrema of a transition probability function for a quantum walker on a graph

Tags: optimization, python, computational-physics, constrained-optimization, quantum-mechanics

## The goal

Implement some Python code to find the extrema points of a function that is strongly oscillating.

## The background

Let $G$ be a connected graph with $n$ points with Laplacian matrix $L(G)$. We may represent each vertex of $G$ as a canonical basis vector $|k\rangle$ for $k\in \{1, ..., n\}$, spanning a *position* Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. A notable element of such a space is the *flat* superposition
$$|s\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}(|1\rangle+|2\rangle+...|n\rangle).$$

Within such a model, assume you are given the Hamiltonian
$$ H(\gamma, w, G)=\gamma L(G)-|w\rangle\langle w|$$
where $|w\rangle$ is one of the position basis vectors and $\gamma$ a real parameter, and consider the probability function $$P_{G,n}(t,\gamma)=|\langle w| U_H(t,\gamma)| s\rangle|^2$$ for a system prepared in the flat state to evolve under $H$ into $|w\rangle$.

---

For a general $G$, $P$ is a strongly oscillating function. Calculating the right maximum for a pair $(\gamma, t)$ given $G, n$ and $|w\rangle$ as fixed parameters is challenging, because most algorithms will rather find something local and then halt.

## My implementation

The flat state $|s\rangle$ and the target state $|w\rangle$ can be implemented in Python as

```
def flat(n):
    s = []
    for j in range(n):
        s.append(1/m.sqrt(n))
    return np.array(s)

def target(n,p):
    w=[]
    for j in range(n):
        if j==p:
            w.append(1)
        else: w.append(0)
    return np.array(w)
```

The probability function is then implemented as

```
def probability(x,G,n,p):
    t,gamma=x 
    w=target(n,p)
    U=expm(-1j*t*(gamma*nx.laplacian_matrix(G).todense()-np.outer(w,w)))
    psi=np.dot(U,flat(n))
    
    return -abs(np.dot(w,psi))*abs(np.dot(w,psi))
```

where I have used an intermediate state $|\psi(t)\rangle=U_H(t)|s\rangle$.

The Scipy library has a function `minimize` in the `scipy.optimize` module (**note**: the reason why the probability function returns a negative quantity is that there is no direct maximizing function, so we find the maxima of $f$ by finding the minima of $-f$). The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). I have used it to implement the `minimizer` function:

```
def minimizer(G,n,p,x0):
    res=minimize(probability,x0,args=(G,n,p))
    return [-res.fun, res.x[0]]
```

returning an array with $-P_{\text{max}}$ and the corresponding $(t_{\text{max}}, \gamma_{\text{max}})$. The argument `x0` is an array containing the initial guess on $t$ and $\gamma$ respectively.

## The issue

scipy.optimize.minimize works only after setting an initial guess `x0`, and the result of the optimization strongly depends on such a choice. As a consequence, obtaining a graph of the parameters that maximize probability as a function of the number of vertices $n$ becomes impossible, as any `x0` is only good in a range $(n_1, n_2)$ with endpoints depending on the chosen graph.

So here I ask for help: is there any way to make sure `minimizer` finds the global minima of `probability` (and in particular the first of them, if there are many) consistently in a dimension range $n \in (0, N\ge 100)$, regardless of the underlying graph?

I hope everything is as clear as possible, and thanks in advance to whoever might answer.

## An example: the complete graph

For $n=20$, the probability function for the complete graph looks like this:
[image]

The complete graph is a good benchmark for testing the code as we know that $P_{\text{max}}=1$ for $t_{\text{max}}=\pi\sqrt{n}/2$ and $\gamma=1/n$ regardless of the chosen vertex $|w\rangle$.

I have written a snippet of code that plots either of these quantities as functions of $n$, taking $|w\rangle=|0\rangle$:

```
#i=0 plots probability_max,  #i=1 plots t_max, #i=2 plots gamma_max
#plots in the interval [n=2, n=maxi) 
def plotComplete(x0,maxi,p,i):
    zPoints = []
    yPoints = []
    refX=[]
    refY=[]

    for z in range(2,maxi):
        y=round(minimizer(nx.complete_graph(z),z,p,x0)[i],5)
        zPoints.append(z)
        yPoints.append(y)

    pyplot.plot(zPoints, yPoints, 'b')
    
    if i==1:
        for z in range(2,maxi): 
            y=m.pi*m.sqrt(z)/2
            refX.append(z)
            refY.append(y)

        pyplot.plot(refX, refY, 'r')
    
    pyplot.show()
```

Calling `plotComplete([0.1,1],100,0,0)` (notice that the initial guess on $t$ is $0.1$; changing it to, for example, $0$ or $1$ gives wildly different results) gives as expected the flat line

[image]

for the first $100$ complete graphs. Calling `plotComplete([0.1,1],100,0,1)` plots $t_{\text{max}}$ with the same initial guess:

[image]

Here, I have made two overlapping plots: the red one is the theoretical value $\pi\sqrt{n}/2$, the blue one is the implemented minimizer. For the most part up to around $n=60$ the two plots are in almost perfect agreement, then after that the initial guess $0.1$ is no more good enough to produce the correct result. The blue spikes appear any time the wrong minimum is found.

Comment: Finding a global minimum in general is not a solvable problem unless you have quite a bit of information on the function to be minimized. For finding a global minimum you'd have to find all local minima and compare them, so to begin with you'd need to know how many local minima are there.

Comment: @MaximUmansky I understand that finding the global minimum is in general a tough problem. I would be happy with something that is *likely* to find it for most $n$ between $0$ and a sufficiently large number (say $100$, or more if possible). A grid-based algorithm with a small enough grid would probably work, but would obviously be quite inefficient. What I would like to see is some idea to strike a balance between performance and accuracy; I am sure there must be someone who has developed a more suitable method for this kind of functions than the one implemented in scipy...

Comment: For example: at the scipy.optimize.minimize doc page there is a list of optimization methods (Nelder-Mead, Powell, CG...) as optional arguments to minimize. I have tested a few of them without finding much difference, but there is probably a method somewhere that is more suitable for treating oscillating functions compared to the others. Another possibility I have looked into is the pyswarm package, though I am yet to thoroughly test it. I guess what I am looking for is advice on what to look for that can at least improve my success rate at finding the minimum.

Comment: One suggestion: If you can provide a plot illustrating the function that would save time for people here who might want to try to understand your problem and propose some ideas.

Comment: @MaximUmansky You are right. I'm going to add a practical example soon.

Comment: @MaximUmansky Done! Please feel free to take a look and give any further advice to make the problem as clear as possible.

Comment: That's good; but where is that oscillating function that has multiple minima, can it be illustrated as well?

Comment: @MaximUmansky I can look into making a 3D plot for the `probability` function, if it can help.

Comment: Does the minimum evolve smoothly with time, or does it jump from one state to another at certain times?

Comment: So the oscillating function depends on 2 real arguments, $\gamma$ and t, and defined over a finite domain $[0,t_{max}] \times [0,\gamma_{max}]$? If so then a contour plot of the function would help understand the structure of the local minima.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I'm not sure I understand the question. The probability should be a smooth function of both $\gamma$ and $t$, once a graph $G$ has been chosen with a certain number of vertices $n$. The *non-smoothness* of the problem depends rather on the choice of the initial guess on time as $n$ is varying in a large enough interval.

Comment: @MaximUmansky $t$ is the time, thus $t\in[0,+\infty)$. $\gamma$ is a real parameter that may be chosen positive (not sure if I specified this in the answer; if not, my bad). I've been tinkering for a while with making a contour plot as I also thought it could be a helpful visualization, but as this stuff is not my forte it is taking me some time... stay tuned.

Comment: @OptimusPrimeNumber What I'm trying to suggest is this: If you know what the minimal energy state is at $t=0$, then this is a good starting guess for what it will be at $t=0+\Delta t$ if $\Delta t$ is small enough -- you only need to search in the vicinity, using a derivative-based method. And then you can do the same for $t+\Delta t$ and so on.

Comment: @MaximUmansky I have added a coloured 3D plot. It shows two things: first, there are periodic peaks at multiples of $\pi\sqrt n/2$, and second, around every peak there are many folds with depth depending on the value of $\gamma$. I think the problem with my algorithm is that sometimes it finds the wrong peak, and sometimes it finds the wrong "fold", so to speak.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Please forgive me, but I am not sure what you mean by *minimal energy state at $t=0$* in relation to my problem. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I guess Wolfgang Bangerth's suggestion is to find first the global minimum at t=0 - that's a 1D problem, so it is much easier - and then go in small increments in time using the global minimum found at the previous time slice as the first guess for the current time slice. This strategy is often used for nonlinear time evolution problems. But to use it here we'd need to know if the global minimum stays on a continuous curve in the $(\gamma, t)$ space. Just visually inspecting the surface plot it does not look to my eye that's the case - the global minimum jumps to a different fold with time.